# Pouchdb simple get by id returns undefined

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have installed PouchDB to replace an ajax/json that was retrieving data from the server to sync with pouchdb locally. The sync worked fine but I have tried in vain to retrieve a doc by id with a db.get. I have stepped through the code and when the get is executed it ignores the rest of the code and exits the function. I have tried the promise with .then and .catch and nada...can someone explain whats happening or what I'm doing wrong. I can see the Pouchdb file in inspect Indexeddb. Here are the code segments.

### TOP OF THE JS FILE (main.js)

```
var db = new PouchDB('product');`
if (typeof window != "undefined") {window.PouchDB = PouchDB; }`
var sync = PouchDB.sync("product", "http://localhost:5984/product",`
{ live: true,`
  retry: true}) ;`
var docrec = {};
var gprodno   = "";
var gdesc = "";

$(function() {
```

.
.
.
CALL TO THE GET FUNCTION
    ----

```
   $('#txtbtn').click(function() {
    //  THIS IS THE KEY FOR THE DOC
    var upcCode = $('#txtupc').val();

    var pget = getProd(upcCode);
       // on return pget is undefined
    $('#txtprod').val(gprodno);
    $('#txtdesc').val(gdesc);
 //   gprodno, gdesc and pget are all undefined after the getProd function
 // is executed
```

.
.
.
GET DOC FUNCTION   ------

```
 //last try at it
 function getProd(upc)
    {
    var rdoc;
    db.get(upc).then(function(result) {
        rdoc =  result.data;
        console.log(rdoc)
        });
    }
        //        gprodno   = rdoc.product;
        //        gdesc = rdoc.proddesc;
});


-------------------------------------------------------------
//PREVIOUS try at it
function getProd(upc)
    {
    db.get(upc, (function(err, rdoc)  {
       if (err) { return console.log(err); }
          gprodno   = rdoc.product;
          gdesc = rdoc.proddesc;  }
      );
    }
```

Comment: When you call db.get(upc) what is the value and type of upc and what is the doc id in the database?